# MYSQL no muestra los días igual a 0 o sin registros

Tags: php, mysql

disculpen cuando realizo una consulta con mysql usando count.

Al querer obtener la menor cantidad de tickets creados por días, no me devuelve los días que no tiene ningún tickets creados.

Consulta

```
SELECT  
    DATE_FORMAT(t.fecha, '%d - %b - %Y') AS fecha, 
    COUNT(t.id) AS total, 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.fecha) AS mes 
FROM tickets t 
WHERE YEAR(t.fecha) = 2022 
AND  month(t.fecha) = 12 
AND t.activo = 1
GROUP BY DATE(t.fecha) 
ORDER BY total
```

Y me devuelve esto hasta el 31 de diciembre, pero el dia 4 y 5 no hubieron tickets creados y esos no me los muestra, alguien sabria decirme como corregirlo por favor.

| fecha | total | mes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 - Dec - 2022 | 3 | 12 |
| 02 - Dec - 2022 | 5 | 12 |
| 03 - Dec - 2022 | 4 | 12 |
| 06 - Dec - 2022 | 2 | 12 |
| 08 - Dec - 2022 | 5 | 12 |

Comment: Al momento de quitarle el group by y order by, que datos obtienes ? Tambien serviria un ejemplo de los datos originales a obtener

Comment: Al quitarle el group by y order by, me traes el mes de diciembre, la fecha del 1 de diciembre y la cantidad total de los tikets que serian 85. NADA MAS

Comment: Ninguna base de datos te va a traer datos que no existen, por lo que con una sola tabla nunca vas a obtener lo que quieres, necesitas hacer al menos un cruce ([LEFT|RIGHT] JOIN) con otra tabla. En este caso eso es una tabla de calendario, sobre la cual irá iterando la consulta. Verifica si te sirve alguna de [estas respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3538858/1545868) - en inglés.

Comment: No hay razón para disculparse por usar count en mysql. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde MySQL 8 no es necesario crear tablas con fechas -ni disparadores-, con una *Expresión de Tabla Común Recursiva* puedes generar un rango de fechas y después hacer un OUTTER JOIN con las fechas de los boletos:

```
WITH RECURSIVE fechas(fecha) as(
  SELECT cast(concat_ws('-',2022,12,1) as date) fecha
  UNION ALL
  SELECT fecha+interval 1 day 
    FROM fechas
    WHERE fecha+interval 1 day <= last_day(fecha)
)
SELECT f.fecha
     , count(t.id) total
     , month(f.fecha) mes 
  FROM fechas f
    LEFT JOIN tickets t 
      ON    t.fecha = f.fecha
        AND t.activo = 1
  GROUP BY f.fecha
--  ORDER BY total
```

En este caso se generan las fechas desde el 1ro de Diciembre hasta el último día del mes (31 de Diciembre), puedes ajustar el rango a tu conveniencia.

Si no tienes MySQL 8 -aunque es recomendable considerar la actualización ya que la versión 5.7 finaliza su ciclo de vida en 2023- la alternativa es usar variables de usuario haciendo JOIN con una tabla cualquiera que tenga la cantidad suficiente de registros, en este caso 31:

```
SELECT f.fecha
     , count(t.id) total
     , month(f.fecha) mes 
  FROM ( SELECT @fe := @fe +interval 1 day fecha
           FROM cualquierTablaConMuchosRegistros
              , ( SELECT @fe:='2022-12-01'-interval 1 day ) v
           WHERE @fe < last_day('2022-12-01')
       ) f
    LEFT JOIN tickets t 
      ON    t.fecha = f.fecha
        AND t.activo = 1
  GROUP BY f.fecha
--  ORDER BY total
```

Comment: Valió ando usando la versión 5.7.23 :c

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta la alternativa para MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como se comentó, no vas a obtener resultados al querer contar registros que no existen en tu tabla, necesitas hacer uso de algun LEFT|RIGHT JOIN para poder operar sobre los registros que necesitas, tal y como te voy a mostrar en un ejemplo más abajo.

**Otra opción** es agregar una columna en donde lleves registro de la cantidad de tickets generados **en cada fecha**, y luego ir incrementando su valor en uno haciedo uso de un **trigger** el cual se ejecute luego de una entrada en la tabla donde registras los tickets en si. (si necesitas ayuda para su desarrollo, no dudes en comentarlo)

##### Ejemplo para left join

Supongamos que tenemos dos tablas: **chosen_game** y **users** con los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y queremos obtener la cantidad de juegos que eligió cada usuario (llevado a tu caso la cantidad de tickets generados por dia), en ese caso la query que tendríamos que usar es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT username, count(id_game) as amount_games FROM users LEFT JOIN chosen_game ON id=id_user GROUP BY id;
```

obteniendo como resultado la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haber comprendido tu problema, y que puedas sacarle fruto a estas posibles soluciones.

Comment: ¿Para qué un trigger? Si hoy mismo puedes crear fechas para 100 años; a menos que sea un dispositivo embebido 36,500 registros de una columna de 3 bytes es muy poco.

Comment: Para que en el momento de que se registre un nuevo ticket en la tabla donde tenga los tickets en si, se modifique automáticamente la nueva columna (ficticia, dónde almacenaría los tickets por fecha) en la tabla donde tiene las fechas. Que sea una opción no significa que sea la más eficiente, a lo mejor le resulta más cómodo que una consulta con joins, que llevado al caso creme que a bajo nivel se trabaja tan bien de ambas maneras que solo va a repercutir si el tamaño de datos es gigantesco.